# Post job in Indeed from our site using PHP and save the job on our portal from Indeed using PHP APIs

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have created a job portal using PHP and MySQL. Now I want to create a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job which posts jobs from my portal to [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeed) as well as I want to post jobs from Indeed to my portal.

I have created an Indeed app in the Indeed developer platform. I have done the following code in my core PHP demo. The code is as given below.

The below code is to get an access token:

```
<?php
// For getting the access token

$url = 'https://apis.indeed.com/oauth/v2/tokens';
$data = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => '99f0224***',
    'scope' => 'employer_access',
    'client_secret' => '4oJlfJXqH***'
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_status == 200) {
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$access_token = $result['access_token'];
echo 'Access Token: ' . $access_token."<br><br><br>";

// For posting a job in Indeed
$job_data = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => '99f022474***',
    'scope' => 'employer_access',
    'client_secret' => '4oJlfJXqHlr9*****'
];
$job_data1 = [
    "mutation" => [
        "jobsIngest" => [
            "createSourcedJobPostings" => [
                "jobPostings" => [
                    [
                        "body" => [
                            "title" => "Test Job From local",
                            "description" => "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet",
                            "location" => [
                                "country" => "US",
                                "cityRegionPostal" => "US, NY 12345",
                            ],
                            "benefits" => [],
                        ],
                        "metadata" => [
                            "jobSource" => [
                                "companyName" => "Test Company",
                                "sourceName" => "TestCompany",
                                "sourceType" => "Employer",
                            ],
                            "jobPostingId" => "JobId1",
                            "datePublished" => "2024-03-18T12:00Z",
                            "url" => "http://example.com/careers/job1.html",
                            "contacts" => [
                                [
                                    "contactType" => ["contact", "recruiter"],
                                    "contactInfo" => [
                                        "contactEmail" => "test@gmail.com",
                                        "contactPhone" => "+91324354",
                                        "contactName" => "SL1",
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$job_data = array_merge($job_data, $job_data1);
$ch1 = curl_init('https://apis.indeed.com/graphql');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($job_data));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'key:99f022474d7****'
]);
$response1 = curl_exec($ch1);
$http_status1 = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($http_status1 == 200) {
    echo 'Job posted successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'Error posting job: ' . $response1;
}
curl_close($ch1);
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . $response;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I am able to access the access_token successfully, but I am not able to post a job. I got an error like:

> Error posting job: {"data":null,"errors":[{"extensions":{"code":"FORBIDDEN"},"message":"Client is not authorized."}]}

Comment: how can we authorized. i am able to get access token using same client key and secret kay. and where to pass that access token in job post API call using curl and php

Comment: how can i check that. if i am able to get access token then i assume i have authorization endpoint access

Comment: Why are you sending `$job_data` in the second request also? That should only be necessary when requesting an access token. Once you have the access token, you should only need to send that in any subsequent requests (until it expires)

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions here precisely? https://docs.indeed.com/authorization/auth-2-legged-oauth . Are you able to call any of the other endpoints using this access token?

Comment: Also I assume this is the endpoint you're attempting to call with your request: https://docs.indeed.com/api/job/mutations/jobsIngest/createSourcedJobPostings ? It's always helpful if you link us to the documentation when asking questions about problems accessing APIs